# Ploting the TSP tour using matpltotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, traveling-salesman

I am using this code snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506375/creating-graphics-for-euclidean-instances-of-tsp) after modifying it to fit with the rest of my python script, I think I have done this modification not the right way.

```
positions = list_points 
# Where list_points(np.array) = [[3.7440e+01 5.4121e+02] [6.1218e+02 4.9432e+02]...[3.8130e+01 3.5315e+02]]
x_sol = np.asarray(t) 
# Where t = [(0.9481610257893822, 37.44, 541.21), ..., (0.9313909810893908, 49.92, 541.44)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (10,10), sharex=True, sharey=True)         # Prepare 2 plots
ax[0].set_title('Raw nodes')
ax[1].set_title('Optimized tour')
ax[0].scatter(positions[:, 0], positions[:, 1])             # plot A
ax[1].scatter(positions[:, 0], positions[:, 1])             # plot B
start_node = 0
for i in range(N):
    start_pos = positions[start_node]
    next_node = np.argmax(x_sol[start_node])
    end_pos = positions[next_node]
    ax[1].annotate("",
            xy=start_pos, xycoords='data',
            xytext=end_pos, textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc3"))
    start_node = next_node

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Because instead of a complete connected tour, where arrows link all the cities in the tour, when It plots it gives:

[image: With my modification]

Just the first one is connected, While It was supposed to give something like this:
[image: Expected]
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In your `for i in range(N)` block you never use the `i` to change the arrow. So you are just plotting that one arrow N times.

Comment: @BenT Thanks for the answer, you are right, Could you please help me to fix it, I mean where should I use the ```i``` in order to update the arrows ?